# Dell Inspiron 5000 won't wakeup after suspend

Tags: 14.04, dell, suspend

I've just replaced Windows with Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Dell Inspiron 5000 series.

Everything seems to be working,  except it won't wake up after I suspend.

If I tap the power button, it *sounds* like it is waking up, the screen seems to light but remains black.

I have to hold down the power button to force a shutdown and reboot.

Any tips on where to look to start looking to debug this gratefully appreciated! Thanks.